# Max-Cut not optimal solution example?

Tags: algorithms

I currently learning about the **Max-Cut** problem, but i'm little bit confused about how the 2-approximation algorithm works. The algorithm is as follows:

1. Start with an arbitrary partition
2. Find a vertex $u$ with more outgoing edges in its own side than to the other.
3. If such a $u$ exists, switch $u$ to the other side and goto Step 2.
4. Otherwise, end the procedure.

I can't find example of a graph that this algotihm *doesn't* return the ***optimal*** solution. can someone give me an example?

Comment: Do you really mean optimal?  Or optimum?  If you mean Optimal, how do you define the neighborhood of the cut?  By all cuts that only differ by 1 vertex possibly?

Comment: The reason I ask is because greedy algorithms always produce optimal solutions.  Unless you want to define the idea of "neighborhood" in a strange way, greedy algorithms basically define the concept of optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an electronic computer to find this answer, a graph with 4 vertices:

[image: Cut Example]

The graph is given in green.  The blue cut is the optimum partition: $\{\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}\}$, with a cut size of 3.

The red cut, $\{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}\}$ has no vertices that your algorithm would move, because they all have equal or more outgoing edges.

Comment: if i change the first line to say : pick the partition were all the vertices are in the same side (which is the whole graph), and the other side will be empty set. and then run the algorithm. you have maybe example for this? tnx a lot!

Comment: @user2637293 Pick the same graph, then just move 1 then 2